# How to pass a instance html_safe string variable to js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, html-safe

It seems a stupid question, but there are no way to achieve this

With Rails 4.2.5.

in a remote call to the controller,

```
def update
  # ... save ...
  @notice="S'han trovat errors"
  # automatically renders update.js.erb
end
```

in update.js.erb

```
alert('<%=(@notice)%>');
```

this is the output:
[image]

What I've tried:

1)In the controller:

```
 @notice="S'han trovat errors".html_safe
```

2)another proof, in js.erb:

```
  alert('<%=raw(@notice)%>');
```

In both cases, when javascript function `alert()` is  executed, it hangs without any message in terminal neither in browser console ¿?

3)I have tried too:

```
alert('<%=escape_javascript(@notice)%>');
```

But doesn't work, shows "S'han trobat..."

*Of course, if I show in `index.html.erb`, **@notice** , the result is correct (S'han trobat..)*

I don't know how to pass from controller to js.erb a " ' " character in a string instance variable to be shown

Thanks

Comment: I've already done, it is one of my proofs, I also have tried `alert('<%=escape_javascript(@notice)%>');` without success

Comment: Have you even looked at the generated code? What's the problem with it in each case?

Answer (score 0):

just remove raw or try add .html_safe in js file not in the controller.

Other solution is to use a \' to escape  single quote  like

@notice="S\'han trovat errors"

Comment: I've already removed raw, and it doesn't work, it is one of my proofs,

Comment: did you try adding \' to scape single quote?

Comment: If I put in @notice "S\\'han trobat" the result is "S&#39;han trobat"

Comment: If I put in @notice "S\'han trobat the result is "S&#39;han trobat" too

Comment: try using the #{} instead of <%= %>, maybe it will work because you are in .erb file. just maybe.

Comment: PUFF!!! the problem is that javaScript recives: alert('S'han trobat..') three semicolons character ( ' ) -> catalan newbie mistake!!, sorry

Comment: or try this alert('escape(<%=@notice%>)');

Comment: If I put `alert(escape('<%=(@notice)%>'));` the result is `S%26%2339%3Bhan%20trobat%20errors`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that javascript recives:

```
alert('S'han trobat errors');
```

there are 3 **'**

So the solution is puting in the controller:

```
@notice="S'han trobat errors".html_safe
```

and in js.erb:

```
 alert("<%=(@notice)%>");
```

Of course, I fell in the quotation marks mistake,

but I still have the question: Why in html.erb files are strings auto-escaped, and they aren't in js.erb? so, why is needed to put `.html_safe` in the string if I want to show it in `js.erb`